# Configuring bind9 to forward subdomain requests to internal DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm attempting to implement a trivial loadbalancer using a DNS server that returns a random IP for a given subdomain. I have the top level domain which is currently handled by bind9, and I'd like to keep it this way. Is there a way I can configure bind9 so that instead of serving the requests for the subdomain directly it instead forwards the request to an internal DNS server, so that this server may return a random IP?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `NS` entry for subdomain only and specify internal DNS server's IP/FQDN, so all subdomain-related requests will be queried from internal DNS.

```
subdomain.domain.com IN NS 123.123.123.123
```